# Display Text of Active Element on Load and Remember

Tags: jquery, css, styles

I am currently using cookie value to switch between style rules. The issue is the text element `.style-value` only shows the active `a href` on `onclick` event. I want this to show on `onload` event too but can't get it to work no matter how much time I've spent on it. What am I missing?

I've gotten this far:

```js
$('#style-switcher a').click(function() {
  $('.style-value').text($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- style switcher -->
<link rel="stylesheet" id="switch_style" href="#">
<div class="main-parent-style-switcher">

  <div class="style-switcher dropdown select-change">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span class="dropdown-label hidden-sm hidden-xs">Theme: </span>
      <span class="style-value"></span>
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul id="style-switcher" class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="style-choice"><a class="default" onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('default'); return false;" href="#">Default</a>
      </li>
      <li class="style-choice"><a class="schwifty" onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('schwifty'); return false;" href="#">Get 
     Schwifty</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /style switcher -->
```

Comment: Please elaborate `setActiveStyleSheet()`

Comment: That is for the style switcher. Once the style sheet is selected it saves a cookie for it. That js is working just fine.

Comment: function setActiveStyleSheet(title) {
  var i, a, main;
  for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
    if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && a.getAttribute("title")) {
      a.disabled = true;
      if(a.getAttribute("title") == title) a.disabled = false;
    }
  }
}

function getActiveStyleSheet() {
  var i, a;
  for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
    if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && a.getAttribute("title") && !a.disabled) return a.getAttribute("title");
  }
  return null;
}

Comment: That's some of the stylesheet switcher code.

Comment: Edit out some irrelevant sentences and add a few words for clarity.

Comment: USAGE:

> User Clicks Theme Dropdown
> User Clicks Theme Name
> Theme Stylesheet is Applied
> Theme Dropdown Reads Theme Name (Default, Orange, Green, whatever)
> Upon REFRESH the theme name is still showing

Comment: ISSUE: Upon refresh, it resets the dropdown element and no longer remembers what theme is selected. That is the ONCLICK function at the top. On Click > Show theme name from A tag #style-switcher > Adds theme name text to .style-value > I want it to remember .style-value once it's refreshed